# Mantener ventana modal de bootstrap persistente al llenar gridview

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap

Lo que estoy haciendo es lo siguiente:

En un formulario de `Asp.Net` un usuario presiona un botón, el cual abre una ventana modal de `Bootstrap` como la que adjunto en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Ventana modal abierta]

Cuando esa ventana modal está abierta, el usuario tiene la posibilidad de capturar un número de BP o un nombre de BP y realizar la búsqueda, de la cual los resultados se deberían mostrar en un `gridview` con las coincidencias. **El problema viene aquí**. Estamos de acuerdo que cuando el usuario presiona el botón `Search` de la ventana modal, para que se muestren los resultados, se hace un `Postback` para poblar el `gridview` con las coincidencias.

Lo que deseo hacer es que la ventana modal permanezca abierta para mostrar los resultados. Ahorita lo que me está haciendo es que la ventana modal como tal desaparece, pero el fondo queda activo, como muestro en la siguiente captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces lo que yo hice dentro del evento de `btnSearchBP_Click`, fue agregar la siguiente línea:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "modal", "$('#addModal').modal('show');", True)
```

Con esa línea ya me muestra la información bien ordenada en el `grid`, pero me agrega un "fondo extra" que no desaparece al momento de hacer mi selección de BP.

Entonces, ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de hacer que la ventana modal quede persistente mientras cargo la información en el `gridview`?

Answer (score 0):

bueno primero el modal de bootstrap lo llame con un boton deasp
agregandole este codigo en el boton

```
OnClientClick="$('#myModal').modal('hide');"
```

despues de llamar el modal, al grid que voy a poner en el modal, le paso un update panel , para que mantenga la consulta y luego es nada mas de estetica en tu modal

```
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnbitacora" EventName="Click" />
       </Triggers>
       <ContentTemplate>
          <fieldset>
             <asp:GridView ID="Grid_bitacora" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
          </fieldset>
       </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```